# Call from AXIS2-Webservice in IIS causes Error (500) - Internal Server Error

Tags: iis, tomcat, apache-axis

I want to call Axis2-Webservice (Standard Example: version-1.6.2.aar) in IIS-WebService (C#). Unfortunately, it returns (500) Internal Server Error.

My configuration:
 IIS Version 7.5 
 Tomcat 6.35
 Axis2 1.6.2

Everything runs on WIN7.
Call from SOAPUI or directly from browser works fine.
Call from IIS-WebService causes error:

Call in c# per:

```
HttpWebRequest GetResponse() Method = "POST"
```